# Protocol or BaseViewController

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I have to set up a project that has to contain several targets. The goal is to have a code base to share it with all the targets that will be created later. I make an example : I will have a `UIViewController` for the login, but this will be different for every target. My idea is to have a code base to share with every specific `LoginViewController`. What is the best approach to structure the code? I started writing a protocol, here it is :

```
protocol LoginProtocol {

    weak var txtUsername: UITextField? { get set }
    weak var txtPassword: UITextField? { get set }
    weak var btnLogin: UIButton? { get set }

    func login()
}
```

The idea is to implement this protocol in every controller.

The other approach is to write a sort of base view controller that every other controller will inherit from. Like this :

```
// MARK: - Instance vars and IBOutlets

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtUsername: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField?
    @IBOutlet weak var btnLogin: UIButton?


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }
}

extension LoginViewController {

    func login() {

        print("Hello")
    }
}
```

What do you think? What is the best choice, architecturally?

Answer (score 0):

Tough to "answer" this since it is to some extent opinion...but here's my input:

I think it boils down to common behavior: If you use a protocol, but then feel like you are writing almost the same code every time you implement it...then you probably want a base class.  I love protocols and use them heavily, but I think people are too quick to dismiss base classes these days.  (There ARE pros and cons, but so many people blindly make protocols without thinking about it.)

I will sometimes use a hybrid of a base class that has a delegate to "configure" certain parts.